# auth attempt failing in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5

I have some post about auth attempt failure but my case seems to be different. Still in dev phase so my password is in plain text. I try to login but i keep getting false and so redirected back to login page.

The error message says username/password does not match but dd reveals that both email and password are correct.

What could be responsible for this failure? PS: it's my first time working with laravel

web.php

```
Route::post('/login', 'AuthController@authenticate');
Route::get('/', 'PostController@index');
```

AuthController

```
public function auth()
{
    //dd($request);

    // attempt to login the user
    if (! auth()->attempt(request(['email', 'password']))) {

        return back()->withErrors([
            'message' => 'Username/Password does not macth'
        ]);
    }

    return redirect('/');
}
```

PostController

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::latest()->limit(3)->get();

    return view('post.index', compact('posts'));
}
```

Comment: Is your password saved has a hash in the database or is visible?

Comment: Password isn't hashed. It's in plain text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this code in your User model and the password will be hashed automatically only if it needs:

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
{
    if( \Hash::needsRehash($value) ) {
        $value = \Hash::make($value);
    }
    $this->attributes['password'] = $value;
}
```

and change your password after, so you have the hashed password in the database

Comment: many thanks...that piece of code worked the magic. I'll learn how to authenticate using make:auth in another test project.

Comment: Im using an alternate model to user model, one that refers to a preexisting table, and have both the model and alternate table defined in config/auth.php in the default users section.  How would I leverage this specified method on that new model, since my passwords are not yet hashed?

Comment: Better if you post a new question, referring to this one, comments are not the right place to examine your case.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understand... but if you are using the Laravel Authentication (`php artisan make:auth`) you will not be storing the password in plain text... so if you are setting the password directly in your db it will not work as it will check the password field in the db with the assumption that it is stored with a dbcrypt hash...

So if you are using the default auth that comes with laravel, use the registration form to create your user account

Since it's your first time working with laravel i would recommend taking a look at https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/17 as it covers the auth concept and gives you a quick walkthrough on setting up user auth

Comment: Thanks. I think the issue is with the password field which is currently in plain text. By the way I didn't use the make:auth since I was following the laracast tutorial. I'll look into it some more just if I can find away around it. Next time I will use the make:auth